# pdfHTML with in-memory CSS

Tags: html, css, itext7

I'm trying out iText7 and trying to piece together how to do things. It seems that I can put in a base URI to grab external resources which I'm assuming if it finds a .css it will apply that? I have a particular situation where it's easier for me to hold the CSS in memory as a string. It seems odd that I can use HtmlConverter.convertToPdf() and pass in HTML as a string but not CSS.

As a secondary question, what happens if it finds multiple CSS files at that base URI?

Finally (sorry for the dump), if the HTML contains FQDN URLs to images, I'm assuming/hoping it will pull the images directly? In other words, I'm hoping I don't also have to store/write those images to the specified base URI?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I put together a quick demo. I found out it *will* download images that have a full URL which is great.

However, it does not seem to be loading the CSS file that is in a folder I specified. The code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(File.ReadAllText("demoHtml.html"));
// this folder, which is relative to the test .exe, contains a file called pdf.css
ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties().SetBaseUri("Content/Pdf");
FileStream fs = new FileStream("itext.pdf", FileMode.Create);
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(sb.ToString(), fs, props);
```

And the CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
table {
    vertical-align: top;
}
td ol {
    -webkit-padding-start: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
thead tr {
    background: #aaa;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Is the CSS file referenced from the HTML you are trying to convert to PDF?

Comment: It wasn't. I was used to a couple of other components where you passed in a CSS file (or string). I was thinking by setting the baseUri that it would apply whatever CSS it found in that folder. But now, thanks to @SamuelD, I see that .setBaseUri() is just there to resolve any relative paths it finds in what it expects to be a full HTML page. Still having issues with some what I would think simple CSS attributes like max-width on images though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution to question 1:

> I'm trying out iText7 and trying to piece together how to do things. It seems that I can put in a base URI to grab external resources which I'm assuming if it finds a .css it will apply that? I have a particular situation where it's easier for me to hold the CSS in memory as a string. It seems odd that I can use HtmlConverter.convertToPdf() and pass in HTML as a string but not CSS.

Many hours i have spent finding the slution for this problem. Everything seemed right and i even asked a support question about the using of CSS files. In contrary to itext5 (itextsharp), itext7 can't manage an url with a space in it.

So locally testing in a path like this: **c:/Path to project/project/name/wwwroot/** won't work (note the spaces)

I didn't notice this at first because i generated my path programmatically to my css folder:

```
 var basepath = env.ContentRootPath + "\\wwwroot\\pdfcss\\";
```

Changed it to:

```
var basepath = @"G:\some-other\directory\pdfcss\";
```

### Solution to question 2:

Now knowing this i could solve your second question:

> As a secondary question, what happens if it finds multiple CSS files at that base URI?

Nothing, you will still have to insert the links into your html in the head element. If this isn't added you will not have any css!

### Solution to question 3:

And indeed:

> Finally (sorry for the dump), if the HTML contains FQDN URLs to images, I'm assuming/hoping it will pull the images directly? In other words, I'm hoping I don't also have to store/write those images to the specified base URI?

You can do the following:

```
<img id="logo" 
src="https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/path/to-image-
logo.png" />
```

Comment: I totally get it now! Thank you! Do you happen to know a full list of styles that pdfHTML officially supports? The image max-width and the tr:nth-child(even) are not being honored. The webkit was also not being honored but that's not so unexpected so I changed that. Image width is pretty important though.